# OTRS search via deep link possible?

Tags: otrs

I want to link to our OTRS (version 5) -- is it possible to create a URL in such a way that a special parametrized search is performed within OTRS?

I'd like to link from a webpage to something like:

https://otrs.charite.de?Ralf.Hildebrandt@charite.de

and that should display all tickets in the queue XYZ and customeruser == Ralf.Hildebrandt@charite.de

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that's not possible out of the box - at least in the way you probably intend to use it. All *real* search functions in OTRS (that I'm aware of) use HTTP-POST. Parameterized POST request using an URL is in principle possible, but strongly discouraged and wouldn't really work if you intend to store those searches as bookmarks or something like that.

**The good news** - you can create a saved search and trigger that via a URL like this:

```
https://url.to.otrs.de/otrs/index.pl?Action=AgentTicketSearch;Subaction=Search;TakeLastSearch=1;SaveProfile=1;Profile=current%20Changes
```

In this case the `Profile=current%20Changes` would be replaced by the name of the search profile ([Special Characters must be encoded](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)).